# Javascript: How to access an imported module variable from inside another imported module?

Tags: javascript, javascript-import

I have a script that imports a lot of different files, like so:

```
<script type="module">
import * as A from '...';
import * as B from '...';
import * as C from '...';
```

I have my own module that I also want to import and use A,B,C in it.
Currently I have this snippet in 'myfile.js':

```
var init = (function () {
    console.log(A,B,C);
})();
export { init };
```

If I add an import after all others like:

```
<script type="module">
import * as A from '...';
import * as B from '...';
import * as C from '...';
import * as my from 'myfile.js';
```

I get errors that A,B,C are not defined. How do I make it work?

EDIT to clarify:

A,B,C exist right after import statements, so I can access them like so:

```
import * as A from ....
console.log(A);
import * as B from ...
console.log(B);
```

I can also access global variables from inside the module, e.g.:

```
import * as A from ....
console.log(A);
import * as B from ...
console.log(B);
import * as my from 'myfile.js'
```

myfile.js:

```
var init = (function (t) {

    console.log(t);

})(window.innerWidth);

export { init };
```

This prints window width.

I'm looking for this like functionality to work:

```
var init = (function (t) {

    console.log(t);

})(A);

export { init };
```

Callback functions is pretty much like importing my module and then call a function and passing A as a parameter to it, I can do it without callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Module resolution was implemented exactly to don't pullulate the global scope and avoid the programmers ask "does this variable exist yet?".
So, you can use the old-styled JavaScript, disabling the module system. Don't use "myfile" as a module, use it as a global import instead:

```
<script src="myfile.js"></script>
```

This is dangerous in case you are using a build phase.

Or, better, you can just avoid any explicit reference to A, B, and C, since you don't know if they exist or not at that point. You can use a callback:

```
var init = function (cb) {
    cb();
};

// use:
import {init} from ...
init(() => console.log(A,B,C));
```

PS. You are mixing old and new syntaxes

Comment: Variables do exits right after they are imported, if that matters. If I console.log A,B,C right after their respective import statements, they will be printed. So you are saying that I can not access anything outside my module scope?

Comment: You are so much confident! I wouldn't be. Yes, you cannot access anything outside your module scope. This is the main purpose of modules

Comment: I'm confident because I run the code - see my EDIT - and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You are exporting them as a component i guess using {} braces for init. if you want to export them as a component you have to use the default keyword alongside your module that you are exporting. Try **export default {init};**

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, scopes are created by code blocks, functions, modules.
So the module variables is not accessible outside of the module (unless explicitly exported using export).

You should import A, B, C inside `myFile.js` if you want to use them in it.

So `myFile.js` would be:

```js
import * as A from '...';
import * as B from '...';
import * as C from '...';

var init = (function () {
    console.log(A,B,C);
})();
export { init };
```

Here is some useful article on [Scopes in JavaScript](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-scope/#4-module-scope)